# Group dictionary values by document field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection in which every document contains a dictionary and other fields. I'd like to group the dictionary by one of the fields, `level`.

**Example collection:**

```
{
    level: 1
    votes: {
            name1: 1
            name3: -1
            }
}
{
    level: 2
    votes: {
            name4: 1
            name1: 1
            }
}
{
    level: 1
    votes: {
            name1: 1
            name3: 1
            name4: -1
            }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    level: 1
    votes: {
            name1: 2
            name3: 0
            name4: -1
            }
}
{
    level: 2
    votes: {
            name4: 1
            name1: 1
            }
}
```

All examples I was able to find did what I want to do on lists, but I have a dictionary and I am not sure whether I can use `unwind` on that or whether I even should.

Can this be done in pymongo/mongodb or do I have to do it in native python3?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would first need to convert the 'votes' object to an array, process it, and then again convert it into an object. The following query can get you the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "votes":{
                $objectToArray:"$votes"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$votes"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "level":"$level",
                "k":"$votes.k"
            },
            "level":{
                $first:"$level"
            },
            "k":{
                $first:"$votes.k"
            },
            "v":{
                $sum:"$votes.v"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "level":1,
            "votes.k":"$k",
            "votes.v":"$v"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$level",
            "level":{
                $first:"$level"
            },
            "votes":{
                $push:"$votes"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "level":1,
            "votes":{
                $arrayToObject:"$votes"
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{ "level" : 2, "votes" : { "name4" : 1, "name1" : 1 } }
{ "level" : 1, "votes" : { "name4" : -1, "name1" : 2, "name3" : 0 } }
```

Comment: I had to add `"` to all `$`-variables to make it work in pymongo. Unfortunately the result isn't right: `[{'level': 2, 'votes': {'name1': 1, 'name4': 1}}, {'level': 1, 'votes': {'name3': -1, 'name1': 2, 'name4':
-1}}]`

Comment: To clarify: You got `name3=1`, I got `name3=-1`, but it should be `0`.

Comment: This worked, thanks. Could you elaborate on the change?

Comment: @dakes I was grouping on the level, key, and value but it's only required on level and key.